# Why is $y(n) = x(n) + x(n-1)$ a low pass filter?

Tags: filters, lowpass-filter

I have found that this is a simple, but bad lowpass filter:

$$y(n) = x(n) + x(n-1)$$

However, I can't understand why it is a lowpass filter. What is its cutoff frequency?

Comment: Your filter is what could be called a "short-term averager with gain":  $(x(n) + x(n-1))/2$ is the _average_ of the current and past samples, twice that gives you the short-term average with a gain of $2$.  A longer-term (but still short-term compared to infinity!) average would be the average of the current and past $k$ sample values, $k > 1$.  It is a low-pass filter since it _smooths_ out short-term variations.  In particular, the highest possible frequency signal $(\cdots, -1, +1, -1, +1, -1, +1, \cdots)$ is nulled by the short-term averager (with or without gain).

Comment: thanks for helping it is clearer to me now. But that filter with low frequency (1,1,1,1,1,1) it going to have too much amplitude.. isnt this a problem?

Comment: _You_ put the gain into the short-term averager; _you_ take it out!

Comment: I get a highpass filter with  (x(n)-x(n−1)) but I only have a upper gain with x(n)+x(n−1) any clue why I have this result? thx in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you have here is the equivalent of a moving-average filter. Specifically, it is a filter of order 1, whose impuse response is

$$h(n)=\delta(n)+\delta(n-1)$$

Taking its $Z$-transform, we get

$$H(z)=1+z^{-1}=\frac{z+1}{z}$$

There is a pole at $z=0$ and a zero at $z=-1$. Plotting the magnitude of the frequency response $H(\omega)\triangleq H(e^{-\imath \omega})=2\vert \cos(\omega/2)\vert$, you get the following curve

[image]

As you can see, this clearly is a low-pass filter. You can easily calculate the cut-off frequency from here on.

Comment: For computation of the _half-power_ point (as opposed to the first null point) as above, see [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.dsp/browse_frm/thread/26603c9936ff6110#)